# SSIS - Lookup - cache is not initialized and cannot be read

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am getting this error continuously and have no idea about the cause.

Error: The cache is not initialized and cannot be read by component "Lookup "
Error: Failed to prepare the cache for providing data.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "Lookup UBN-StatTypeID" (2021) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0010204.

[image]

Comment: It appears the cache is not initialized. Either your Connection Type is incorrect or you need a precursor step to populate the cache connection manager

Comment: I just replaced two new fields added in table, data type and length same, only difference is those new fields are NULL now means no data so search result may be nothing. Still should not give me error. Should I add a no match error too. Before it was not there and was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Cache Connection Manager, the cache must be populated before the lookup operation, using a Cache Transformation inside a DataFlow.

This error suggests that it's that previous operation which has failed, not a problem with the Lookup Transformation itself.

Comment: This answer is more accurate as one of my colleague told me the same thing and I found it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of your connection in your `Lookup Component` :

**In General tab -> Connection Type -> OLE DB connection manager**

Comment: But I want to use the result set from OLE DB Source plus derive column. It was working and after change of 2 fields with other 2 fields, it stopped working. Need to know the cause.

Comment: Ok I have decided to use OLE DB connection manager for this problem to solve it.